# Периодический просмотр содержимого файла и сообщение о входе пользователя в систему

Tags: bash, linux

Написать скрипт, который периодически просматривает содержимое /var/log/secure и при входе пользователя в систему сообщает на терминал /dev/tty0 о том, что пользователь зарегистрировался.

Comment: на сколько периодически?

Comment: неважно какая периодичность, пусть даже это будет 5 сек., я так понимаю это можно записать так
sleep 5

Answer (score 1):

Заплатить 15$

бесплатно, только подсказки

- tail -f /var/log/secure
- grep
- wall
- write
- mesg

периодичность

- anacron